# Why are questions not related to games allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

You can see how many "non-game-related" questions there are solely for Playstation 4: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps4
Because computers can play games too, *in theory* every PC tech support request could be asked here, especially if about a gaming laptop or a prebuilt gaming PC. What I hope most is that **Arqade only allowed questions strictly related to games**. There are other venues for tech support, for example [Superuser](https://superuser.com/), [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), and [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) (Apple). There are countless of questions on the Arqade frontpage every day I can't answer because I'm solely a Windows user (I have access to older console games thanks to emulators though).

Answer (score 6):

PS4 is a gaming console and pretty much everything you do with it except watching Netflix is gaming related (but well, [that is/was on topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26069/trying-to-install-netflix-app)). I just checked some questions on the tag, the less-gaming related questions are about hardware or apps. [Questions about gaming related hardware and utilities are on-topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

PC tech support is not available here because it is too broad and can have pretty much nothing to do with gaming and therefore those must be asked in their StackExchange websites, the three you linked (also AskUbuntu). We allow questions about gaming-related software though.

If you don't want to see those questions, you can block the tags xbox360, xbox-one, ps3 and ps4 (and 3ds and wiiu etc, you get the idea) [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current).

Comment: Thanks for telling about blocking tags, but I don't agree that "pretty much everything with PS4 is gaming-related". The new consoles and partially the generation before were built to be multimedia platforms. DVD playback was a major factor in PS2's success.

Comment: @user598527 ps2 came out 16 years ago, in march 2000. It is literally 8 months older than me. Nowadays, physical media is pretty much dead. I don't think the majority of PS4 users use it to watch blu-ray/dvd.

Comment: @user598527 Rather than just comparing consoles directly to a PC, I'd suggest taking a browse of our [steam] tag. The Steam platform has the sorts of features that gamers would be knowledgeable about, such as profiles, achievements, the store, and so on. It's far more in line with consoles than just straight PC, and the support we provide comes from people who use/interact with the platform on a regular basis. Needless to say, it's definitely within our expertise as a site, as are the PS & Xbox features.

Comment: @Avery: See [Ars Tecnica's study](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2017/06/xbox-unleashed-our-deep-dive-study-of-how-millions-use-xbox-live/) covering nearly million Xbox Live accounts, by estimate 55% of the time is used for playing games on Xbox One, 40% on Xbox 360. [submitted again to correct a mistake]